# How to integrate extent reports with karate framework using karateoptions. Any sample implementations?

Tags: karate

How to integrate extent reports with karate framework. I have paid version of extent reports. I could not find any sample implementations for extent report with karate. How to use extent reports in karate ? How to use listeners ? example implementation will help more

Comment: All the information known about this area at this point in time is in this thread: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619 - please read it.

Since you have a paid version of extent you could try asking them to help you also.